# React Native text input continues writing 0s

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, textinput

```
          <TextInput
            keyboardType="decimal-pad"
            placeholder="0"
            value={repetitions?.toString()}
            onChange={(e) => {
              if (e.nativeEvent.text && !isNaN(parseInt(e.nativeEvent.text)) && parseInt(e.nativeEvent.text) > 0) {
                setRepetitions(parseInt(e.nativeEvent.text));
              } else {
                setRepetitions(null);
              }
            }}
            style={createGoalStyle.numberInput}
            maxLength={3}
          />
```

If I receive a 0 (or multiple 0s) by the user I want the textinput to fallback to the placeholder but the textInput allows introducing zeros even when i'm setting repetitions to null, what is happening?

Comment: What's `setRepetitions`? Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: It's just part of an useState hook with repetitions

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as follows & add validation on the `value` property:

```
value={repetitions !== null ? repetitions.toString() : ''}
```

Here is the full code:

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType="decimal-pad"
  placeholder="0"
  value={repetitions !== null ? repetitions.toString() : ''}
  onChange={(e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.text && !isNaN(parseInt(e.nativeEvent.text)) && parseInt(e.nativeEvent.text) > 0) {
      setRepetitions(parseInt(e.nativeEvent.text));
    } else {
      setRepetitions(null);
    }
  }}
  style={createGoalStyle.numberInput}
  maxLength={3}
/>
```

Comment: Let me know if it is not working

Comment: Good to know that